# Running "saas:dev" (sass) task Bus Error: 10

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am running grunt-sass to try and compile my SCSS, but any time I run I get a Bus Error: 10. Using Node version 5.6.0, and an image of the error can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za7RL.jpg).

Anyone come across this before?

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Configure tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    beautify: true,
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: false,
                    preserveComments: 'all'
                },
                src: 'src/js/*.js',
                dest: 'js/script.min.js'
            },
            build: {
                src: 'src/js/*.js',
                dest: 'js/script.min.js'
            }

        },
        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    'src/lad.css': 'src/sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: 'src/js/*.js',
                tasks: ['uglify:dev']
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

    // Register tasks

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:dev', 'sass:dev']);

    grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify:build']);
};
```

Comment: Which version do you use? i mean nodejs and grunt.

Comment: I'm not that into grunt, i use gulp. But is there a way instead of running `grunt` to start a watcher (as i can see in your image), to run something like `grunt-sass` as a one time task and see if you have the same error?

Comment: Can you do me a quick favor? `npm i -g npm-check-updates` navigate to your repo/project and `ncu -a` and `npm update` then run it again? That'll sort out any possible version errors.

Comment: Ayoub I am using version 5.6.0 of nodejs, and 0.4.5 of grunt.
Peter I dont think running a watcher would help because the task itself can't run in the first place.
Suzumakes, thanks for that, I just tried all that and it just updated jshint, everything else is up to date. Nothing changed, still getting bus error:10

Comment: [What does your Sass look like?](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/157) Only other thing I can find for you.

Comment: Think you've found it! I had a infinite import loop somewhere, CodeKit didn't notice it because it supported Bourbon itself. Thanks a million! Any way I could get the bounty to you through the comments?

Comment: Yeah don't worry about it, but maybe you should post an answer for your question with the code you had to change to make it work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the issue here was that I had set up my SCSS wrong, a module was importing itself. In this case it was Bourbon Neat, and bourbon was importing itself.

Answer (score 0):

It may be version error. Try to upgrade nodejs and/or grunt. The error is already here reported :

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/204

Comment: I'm all up to date as far as I can tell. I'm running version 5.6.0 of nodejs, and 0.4.5 of grunt.